# Oracle numeric or value error pl/SQL

Tags: java, sql-server, oracle, plsql, oracle11gr2

Hi I have written a procedure in the package to insert the data as follow :

```
create or replace package Proj2_student_reg_package is
    type data_cursor is ref cursor;

procedure add_students(sidIn IN students.sid%type, fnameIn IN students.firstname%type,
                        lnameIn IN students.lastname%type, statusIn IN students.status%type,
                        gpaIn IN students.gpa%type, emailIn IN students.gpa%type,
                        ret_message OUT varchar2);

end Proj2_student_reg_package;
/

create or replace package body Proj2_student_reg_package as

procedure add_students(sidIn IN students.sid%type, fnameIn IN students.firstname%type,
                        lnameIn IN students.lastname%type, statusIn IN students.status%type,
                        gpaIn IN students.gpa%type, emailIn IN students.gpa%type,
                        ret_message OUT varchar2)
is
begin
insert into students values(sidIn ,fnameIn,lnameIn,statusIn,gpaIn,emailIn);
COMMIT;
ret_message := 'Success';

EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
ret_message := 'Error';
end add_students;




end Proj2_student_reg_package;
​
```

and I am calling through a java program :

```
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Types;
import java.util.Scanner;

import oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes;
import oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource;

public class AddStudent {
    public void addStudent(){
        Scanner line = new Scanner(System.in);
        try
        {       

            //Connection to Oracle server
            OracleDataSource ds = new oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource();
            ds.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe");
            Connection conn = ds.getConnection("*****", "****");

            System.out.print("Enter the sid: ");
            String sid = line.next();
            System.out.print("Enter first name: ");
            String fname = line.next();
            System.out.print("Enter last name: ");
            String lname = line.next();
            System.out.print("Enter status: ");
            String status = line.next();
            System.out.print("Enter gpa: ");
            String gpa = line.next();
            System.out.print("Enter email: ");
            String email = line.next();


            CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall("{call Proj2_student_reg_package.add_students(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");

            cs.setString(1, sid);
            cs.setString(2, fname);
            cs.setString(3, lname);
            cs.setString(4, status);
            cs.setString(5, gpa);
            cs.setString(6, email);
            cs.registerOutParameter(7, Types.VARCHAR);

            cs.executeQuery();
            System.out.println(cs.getString(7));
            cs.close();
            //line.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException e) { System.out.println("SQLException " + e.getMessage());}
        catch (Exception e) {System.out.println(e);}
    }

}
```

my students table is :

```
create table students (sid char(4) primary key check (sid like 'B%'),
firstname varchar2(15) not null, lastname varchar2(15) not null, status varchar2(10) 
check (status in ('freshman', 'sophomore', 'junior', 'senior', 'graduate')), 
gpa number(3,2) check (gpa between 0 and 4.0), email varchar2(20) unique);
```

I am giving the values from java program as sid : `B987, fname : akki, lname : aror, satus : junior , gpa : 3,email : xyz@gmail.com..`

But this is giving me an error :

```
SQLException ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

I tried to find too much but I couldn't figure out where the mistake is.
Can anyone tell me the mistake and help me to fix the error.

Comment: Just for starters, `sid` is `char(4)` but you are attempting to send a 5-character string.  That may or may not cause this particular error but it's going to be a problem.

Comment: Also, please take some time to properly format the code and data in your post.  When asking for someone's help, make it easy for them to help you.

Comment: @JimGarrison I typed wrong I am sending in sid as B987.

Answer (score 1):

In your `CallableStatement` `cs` object, you need to change from `cs.setString(5, gpa)` to `cs.setDouble(5, gpa);` as **`gpa` is `number` type in the database**.

Comment: I tried but error not solved. I dont think that is the problem because I have declared gpa as string and sending as string and in the procedure it is getting converted from %type.

Comment: Look at your insert satement: `insert into students values(sidIn ,fnameIn,lnameIn,statusIn,gpaIn,emailIn);` there is no conversion there, so you need pass gpa as setDouble as shown above